# .htaccess clashing in two htaccess in two subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a directory with the following structure:

```
Domain/job (folder)
--.htaccess
--job.php

Domain/offering-page (wordpress folder)
--.htaccess
--othersfile

job/.htaccess code:-

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ job.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ job.php?url=$1

offering-pge/.htaccess code:-

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have problem in only offering-page folder. When I go to the `domain/offering-page/`.  It displays home page it's ok. But, when I go to other page its display the `job/job.php` content. What is wrong in `job/.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

In your regex don't use unescaped hyphen in the middle of a character class. Also you can combine both rules into one:

**job/.htaccess code:-**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)\.html$ job.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```